# Making tab text font bold for shinydashboard

Tags: shiny

I want to make the font bold for the marked content(tabs name) in the below image

```
material_side_nav_tab_content(
    side_nav_tab_id = "example_side_nav_tab_1",
    material_tabs(
        tabs = c(
            "Churn Facets" = "first_tab",
            "Customer Scorecard" = "second_tab"
        )
),
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproductible example ?

Comment: There is no image linked.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

You can wrap the `material_tabs` in a `div` and style the font-weight:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

ui <- material_page(
  title = "Basic Page + Side-Nav + Tabs",
  material_side_nav(fixed = FALSE,
                    tags$h3("Side-Nav Content")),
  div(material_tabs(
    tabs = c("First Tab" = "first_tab",
             "Second Tab" = "second_tab")
  ), style = "font-weight: bold;"), # "font-weight: normal;"
  material_tab_content(tab_id = "first_tab",
                       tags$h1("First Tab Content")),
  material_tab_content(tab_id = "second_tab",
                       tags$h1("Second Tab Content"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```